# Mockito: "given...will" returning null instead of answer

Tags: java, mockito

I am currently restructuring my unit tests. The structure now is like that:

Test-class:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private Service serviceMock;

    private TestData testDataInstance = new TestData();

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        testDataInstance = new TestData();
        testDataInstance.mockRepository();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSth(){
        ...
    }
}
```

TestData-class:

```java
public final class TestData{
    // this is of course an implemented repo
    @Mock
    public JpaRepository repository;

    public final TestDataObj testDataObj = new TestDataObj();

    public void mockRepositories(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.testDataObj.mockJpaRepository(jpaRepository);
    }
}
```

TestDataObj-class:

```java
public class TestDataObj{
    public List<DataClass> testData = new LinkedList<DataClass>(...);

    public void mockJpaRepository(JpaRepository repo){
        given(repo.foo(Mockito.any(bar.class))).will(new Answer<List<DataClass>>(){
            public List<DataClass> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute the testSth()-method, the JpaRepository Mock is there but the foo method returns null, even though it should at least return an empty list.

The idea behind nesting the mockup of the repository is reusability.

Questions:
1. Is the service mock created before or after the setUp-method?
2. Is it even possible to call given...will within a nested object as I did?

Comment: In this case it seems to be not possible to Mock the JpaRepository in the TestData-Class (even though the class calls MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)). As soon as I Mocked the repositories in ServiceTest it started to work, but I'm not really sure why...